# Every graph $G$ containing a cycle satisfies $g(G) \le 2\text{diam}(G) +1$

Tags: graph-theory, proof-explanation

The question I am asking is in reference to [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/325517/relation-between-girth-and-diameter-of-g).

In the second line of the proof it says

> If $g(G) \ge 2\text{diam}(G) + 2$ then $C$ has two vertices whose distance in $C$ is at least $\text{diam}(G) +1$.

I am not convinced by the line. Can anyone help me understanding this ? Why the existence is guaranteed ?

In the fourth line it says

> Thus $P$ contains a $C-path$ $xPy$.

What is meant by $xPy$ ? I know that if $P = {x_0x_1 \cdots x_k}$ is any path then $xPy$ means ${xx_0x_1\cdots x_ky}$. In this case $P$ is already from $x-y$ , then why is it mentioned again ? I am unable to understand it.

I was viewing the [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/493193/384535) given in the end of the [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/325517/relation-between-girth-and-diameter-of-g), where everything was good untill it says

> The easiest way to see this, is to note that $x_{j-1},x_j, \cdots ,x_m $ is a portion of the path $P_C$, hence its length is at most $d+1$ , my doubt is **why at most ?**
>   I think it to be atleast .

I will be thankful if my doubts are cleared. Also I will welcome any fresh explanatory proof of the theorem. Thank you.