# The number of edges when girth is large

Tags: graph-theory, extremal-graph-theory

For any positive constant $c$, the [girth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Girth_(graph_theory)) of graph $G$ is at least $cn$, where $n$ is the number of vertices. Show that, the number of edges, $\vert E \vert \leq n + o(n) $.
Now I know that we should consider the function $f(n) = max \{e(G) \} -n$, where the graph $G$ is as above. A claim states that $\frac{f(n)}{n}$ is decreasing.

Comment: I completely lost you. Can you please clarify the order of the quantifiers?  
Is it:  
Let $G=(V,E)$ some graph. prove: $$\exists c>0\ \  s.t\text{ the girth of G is at least } cn\implies \vert E\vert\leq n + o(n)$$

Comment: @TheHolyJoker thank you very much! A little difference is that I actually mean the statement is true for any positive constant c. It’s very nice of you for help!

Comment: So is it:  

Let $G=(V,E)$ some graph. prove: $$\forall c>0\ \  s.t\text{ the girth of G is at least } cn\implies \vert E\vert\leq n + o(n)$$ 

I think you meant to ask something else. The proof for this is: 
Since $G$'s girth is obviously less than $2n$, the first statement is false for every graph $G$.

Since $False\implies Everything$, the proposition is true. 
Maybe $c$ has to follow additional constraints?

Comment: @TheHolyJoker, the girth is also $\le n$, but $c$ is intended to be a constant between $0$ and $1$. for example, if you let $c = \frac{1}{2}$ so the question asks to show that a graph with such large girth ($\frac{n}{2}$) must be very sparse.    
The question (if I understand it correctly) may be rephrased as follows:  $$g(G)\in \Omega(n) \rightarrow e(G) \le n + o(n)$$ 
Where $g(G)$ is the girth of the graph and $e(G)$ is the number of edges

Comment: @TheHolyJoker For large c, the inequality implies that the girth is infinity, that is, if there is no cycle, we define girth as infinity, and when there is no cycle, the statement is obviously true. Thus we only need to consider small c.

Comment: @AsafRosemarin OK great! thanks! BTW, I'm not sure $c\in (0,1)$ is equivalent to your second statement, but the second statement is well defined.

Comment: @TheHolyJoker $c$ doesn't really have to be in $(0,1)$, it's just that for $c \ge 1$ the statement is trivial (as you said) and we only care about the case $c\in (0,1)$. I think you may be interperting the question like this $$(\forall c >0:  g(G_n) \ge cn) \rightarrow e(G_n) \le n + o(n)$$ but it's actually meant to be $$\forall c > 0: (g(G_n) \ge cn) \rightarrow e(G_n) \le n + o(n)) $$ which is equivalent to $$(\exists c > 0: g(G_n) \ge cn) \rightarrow e(G_n) \ge n + o(n)$$ which is what you said at first, which is finally equivalent to $$g(G_n)\in \Omega(n) \rightarrow e(G_n) \le n + o(n)$$

Comment: Now I lost you again. Is $G_n$ fixed graph with n vertices? or $G_n$ is the set of all undirected graphs with exactly n vertices. And I guess it should be true for all $n$?

Comment: Well if we use $o$ and $\Omega$ then we are regarding asymptotical behavior. So we want that for every sequence of graphs $\{G_n\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ such that $\forall n\in \mathbb{N}:v(G_n)=n$ (it doesn't really have to be that way, but assume for conveniency) the conditions I wrote should happen for sufficiently large $n$'s (Which is why it's equivalent to last one with the $\Omega$)

Answer (score 1):

**

## Not a full answer

**

### Proposition:

Let $G=(V,E)$ be a graph with $n$ vertices. For $k=O(1)$ with respect to $n$ 
$$\text{girth}(G)\geq\frac{n}{k}\implies \vert E\vert\leq(n-1)+k$$

### Conclusion:

$$\text{girth}(G)\in\Omega(n)\implies E(G)\leq n+\color{red}{O}(1)\implies\text{girth}(G)\in\Omega(n)\implies E(G)\leq n+\color{red}{o}(n)$$

Proving the proposition seems, at first sight, simple.
For example by using the fact that if $G$ contain a cycle, then $g(G)\leq 2\cdot\text{Diam}(G) + 1$, which was proved [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/325517/641481)

I'll try to write a complete proof it this hint does not help you, or was trivial.

Comment: I’m confused about this proposition: it seems true when k is much smaller than n. However, for a general integer k, we can find a counterexample such as, for a complete bipartite graph $K_{n,n}$, the girth is 4 but the number k is much larger than n. Could you show more details about this proposition? According to the statement, I think $\frac{n}{k}$ may be an average number of the length of cycles in $G$, but I fail to complete the proof.

Comment: You're right. Without restrictions on $k$, the proposition is probably wrong. But I only need the proposition to hold when $k=O(1)$ with respect to $n$. I think the proposition is true for $k=O(\log(n))$ but I have to think about it.

Comment: thank you. I’ve found the result by Bollobás and Szemerédi. The title of their paper is “Girth of Sparse Graphs”.

Comment: Did they prove it for $k=O(1)$? I could not find the paper for free.

Answer (score 1):

$\mathbf{Intuition:}$
The question intuitively is asking us that if the graph is super sparse, then does it behave more or less like a tree? One more way of looking at the problem is that the average degree must go more towards 2 and that the number of vertices of large degree must vanish. We just have to make this rigorous.

$\mathbf{Proof:}$
Start with some $\epsilon > 0$ such that girth $\geq \epsilon n$ . Suppose for the sake of contradiction, if $\frac{e(G)-n}{n}$ doesn't go to zero, there is a $\delta>0$ such that $e(G)>(1+\delta)n$ for a sequence of $n$ going to infinity. Clearly, for a graph with maximal edges, it can't have zero degree vertices. Now, excise all vertices of degree one, we lost the same amount of edges and vertices. Keep doing this till all vertices are of degree 2 or higher. We can see that in the new graph $G'$, $e(G')>(1+\delta)V(G')$.

Now, perform the following operation on the graph $G'$. If there is a path or a cycle of length greater than $\frac{1+\delta}{\delta}$ such that the endpoints of the path (if it's a cycle, delete the whole thing) are of degree more than 2, delete all the vertices except the end points. For a path or cycle, we lose $g$ edges and $g-1$ vertices. A calculation gives that the new graph after performing this also satisfies $e(G'')>(1+\delta)V(G'')$. Also, make the following observation, by removing these vertices and edges, we do not actually lose girth in the graph. In fact, it can only become higher. If we actually end up with an acyclic graph after these deletions, then the result is at most a tree and we can then get the no. of edges and vertices for the tree easily and see the $\frac{e(G)-n}{n}$ does go to zero.

Now, contract the vertices of degree 2 in this graph $G''$ to arrive at a graph $G'''$ of minimal degree 3 (possibly with loops). Each edge corresponds to a path or cycle in $G''$ of length at most $\frac{1+\delta}{\delta}$. The graph $G'''$ of minimal degree 3 must contain a cycle of length lesser than $2log_2(V(G'''))$. The vertices in $G'''$ is at most the no. of vertices in $G''$ as we don't introduce new vertices.

From this, we have that there is a cycle in $G''$ of length at most

$2(\frac{1+\delta}{\delta})log_2(V(G'')) \leq 2(\frac{1+\delta}{\delta})log_2(n)$. But the girth of $G''$ is at least the girth of $G$ which is $\epsilon n$. And this can't hold for large enough $n$, which gives us a contradiction.

Comment: Got this question in an assignment this week on an Extremal Graph theory course. Ending up solving it and decided to put the answer here for anyone else who might be interested.

Comment: I’m having trouble understanding the last step when we do contraction. Why the number of vertices of degree 3 has such a lower bound? K_{2,m} may be a counterexample, which will be two vertices with m multi-edges.

Comment: I think I can understand what to do after contraction. The girth is O(n), after contraction, there is no loops and no multi-edges, otherwise we can find a cycle of length O(1). So G’’’ is a simple graph of minimum degree at least 3, which forces the girth to be o(n), a contradiction.

Comment: I got the point! Since the girth is O(n), we only contract paths. And after the contraction, a cycle of length L in G’’ will be a cycle of length at least \delta L / (1 + \delta), which is still O(n). But the minimum degree at least 3 implies the girth is o(n).

Comment: Okay, I fixed the degree argument mistake I've made and the proof seems fine now. Take a look and leave an upvote if it's okay.

Comment: Very nice proof! Thank you!